# look for a forum in php module

Tags: php, phpbb, forums

I am looking for a forum script in PHP.
Some time ago I installed **phpBB** but I had to remove it since my site was hacked and attacks cam from **some security problems** in this script.

So I am looking for a **popular php forum script that has NO SECURITY FAILS** like phpbb.
Any recommendations ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no application that's free from security holes. You always have a certain risk, no matter what you do.

Comment: You know what they say: Every program having more than three lines has a bug somewhere. For web applications this is usually a security bug. Remember to install security updates for your script and that's about how far you can go without paying for custom security audit.

Comment: FUDforum. It's not as popular, and hardly as user-friendly. But it looks relatively safe (still using SQL concat, but otherwise code looked okayish). Gotcha: Development seems to have ceased recently. (FUDforum forum broken).

Answer (score 1):

Did you use phpBB2, well phpBB3 is much stronger and has tighter security than phpBB2. I've used phpBB3 for so long and find it the most perfect forum software which is also open-source. I wouldn't go for vBulletin since I find it so overrated and has too much things built in and it's a huge forum software.

So my suggestion is go for phpBB3 if you went for phpBB2, it's always important to stay up to date with the latest revisions.

Or perhaps use [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You always need to keep you're software fully patched to the latest versions, otherwise they are all unsafe.

Answer (score -2):

There is really no such thing as a fully secure forum. All popular forum scripts have some or the other exploits. You may want to move to a commercial solution like vBulletin, IPB etc. instead. Or you may want to use some obscure little known forum (just search for PHP forum in google). Or if you are really paranoid, they why don't you try hosted forums? They are safe and the security is their headache and not yours:

http://www.google.com/search?q=hosted+forums

Comment: Just because someone else hosts the forum, if it is your forum then you are the one who needs to be concerned about security. If the forum gets hacked it is still your data at risk and your site that could be defaced.